# How can I extract the audio from a video file?

Tags: video, audio, mov

I have a video of a music performance that I downloaded online, and want to extract the audio so that I can store it as a music file. It's a MOV file with the Codecs - "XVID, MPEG Layer 3." What software should I use for best results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up using [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) for this, was incredibly simple.

Answer (score 4):

I can't tell you about **best** results, but for some results:

#### VLC, FFMPEG, or MPLAYER

VLC has a GUI and a Wizard. ffmpeg and mplayer example [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/229/extract-audio-from-video-or-online-stream/).

Comment: mankoff, with VLC, I don't see a way to exclude the video. Even if you don't choose the option to transcode the video, it will be included in the output in its original format. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

If it is a `MOV` file which you can open with QuickTime Player, open it QuickTime Player 7, an optional install in Snow Leopard, and then go to `File -> Export`, and choose Sound to AIFF for instance. The resulting AIFF file can me converted back to MP3 or AAC with iTunes, for instance.

Comment: Looks like I need Quicktime Pro for this, as File -> Export is grayed out and there is a PRO label next to it.

Comment: I see. I don't have QTPro, and it works for me; I discovered it's because I have one of the Pro Apps (http://www.apple.com/pro/), which seems to unlock QTPro'd features.